# Using wordpress shortcode, profile and checksum

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to include a checksum to a wordpress page showing a profile throw a shortcode? It works when linking to the profile: [http://example.org/civicrm/profile/edit?reset=1&gid=IDNUMBER&{contact.checksum}&id={contact.contact_id}](http://example.org/civicrm/profile/edit?reset=1&gid=IDNUMBER&%7Bcontact.checksum%7D&id=%7Bcontact.contact_id%7D) but does it work with a shortcode?

The users don't have an account on WP.

Could there be an option in the shortcode to say 'allow checksum' for example: [civicrm component="profile" gid="36" mode="edit"]?